# How can I move to the next array element?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I'm trying to assign a number in an array one by one. If the pointer is pointing at the first element of the array, then it means that the array is empty and it will be assigned with a number. But for some reason, it doesn't seem to move the pointer to the next element. How can I fix this?

```
unsigned char number= '1'; //random number
unsigned char array[8];
int count = 0;
unsigned char *ptr;


int main(){
    while(count < 5){
        reserve();
        count ++;
        ptr++; //move to next element
    }
}

void reserve(void){
    if(ptr = array){          //if pointer is at the first element of the
        *ptr = number;         //array then it means it's empty
    }
    else{                    //not empty array
        *ptr = number;
    }  
}
```

EDIT:
`if(ptr = array)` was a typo. The problem was not assigning the initial value for `*ptr`. I have a new question, though. Someone who commented below said not to use global variables. I had thought about using `static unsigned char *ptr = array` in the `reserve` function, but that would reset to the initial assignment when it is called again. What did that person mean by using explicit dependencies?

Comment: `=` is for assignment, `==` is for comparisons.

Comment: For one, `if(ptr = array)` look at that carefully, pretty sure assignment wasn't on the agenda. Second, both of those blocks (the if-true and else-false blocks) do *exactly* the same thing, so what possible difference in behavior were you shooting for?

Comment: Tip: Avoid global variables. Make your function's dependencies explicit.

Comment: `if(ptr = array){` means `if ptr != 0` (after assignment ptr = array) then  `*ptr = number;`

Comment: Think too about what `unsigned char *ptr;` is pointing to. It will never equal `array` anyway.

Comment: @WhozCraig Well, they both assign the same number, but what I'm trying to go for is assigning an element, then moving on to the next one.

Comment: Your `if` is using the _assignment_ operator `=` but you want the _equality_ operator `==`. So, you want: `if (ptr == array)`. But, you're doing the _same_ thing in each part of the `if/else`, namely: `*ptr = number;`. So, unless you plan to do something different, you can simplify the `reserve` function to be _just_: `*ptr = number;`

Comment: @tadman would putting unsigned char *ptr= array in reserve() function solve the problem? I was assuming that once it is called again the ptr variable will be reset again.

Comment: You can "solve" the problem by skipping all of the pointer mess in the first place. If you want/need to use pointers then you must assume the responsibilities that comes with that, as per the [Rule of Three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)). You can't treat pointers as dumb data properties, they require special handling.

Comment: It doesn't help that you've continually updated the code in your question with "hotfixes" you've gleaned from the comments thus far. It heavily confuses the discussion surrounding your code, as now half the comments don't actually have any relevance. The way to "solve the problem" is to not write code like this in the first place. I would encourage you to find a good C textbook and start from the basics, as your understanding of fundamental program structure and syntax is lacking.

Comment: At the end of the day, you're simply trying to fill an array. There are endless examples of this done correctly, and you've over complicated it greatly. One simple `for` loop "solves" this: `for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) array[i] = value;`

Comment: I agree with Oka. Applying "hot fixes" makes comments and answers seem out of context. So, I've rolled back to your first post. The proper way to handle feedback is to leave the original code block intact. You can append the fixes in separate code blocks at the bottom of your question. This maintains the integrity of SO's Q&A format and allows others to see the progression. Both are important for making the question useful to others in the future and helping responders here produce better results/answers for you.

Comment: @CraigEstey thank you for the clarification. I didn't know that was the way to handle the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: The first paragraph is incorrect. See Oka's comment.

You are initialising a pointer but it doesn't point to anything. This is considered dangerous because when you use it, it just points to a random (not actually random but may as well be) memory address.

You could use (array + count) to step through the array (best not to step array itself as then you run the risk of forgetting and losing the address to the array creating a memory leak).

Also as some comments have pointer out you need to use `==` for comparison.

```
int main(){
    uint number = 1;
    unsigned char array[8];
    // a for loop is a good way to have a loop that ends when a condition is met with an incrementing variable 
    for (int count = 0; count < 4; count++){
        reserve(array+count);
    }
}

void reserve(char * ptr){
    if(ptr == array){          //if pointer is at the first element of the
        *ptr = number;         //array then it means it's empty
    }
    else{                    //not empty array
        //do someting else? Or just set them all equal to number
    }  
}
```

Comment: `ptr` is a global variable, and thus is initialized to `NULL` at runtime. This is canceled out by the assignment in the `if` statement.

Comment: What happens if you try to use the value of null pointers?

Comment: Following the flow of their original program, they never do that.

Comment: You're misunderstanding. The global `unsigned char *ptr` is initialized to `NULL`. `if(ptr = array)` caused `ptr` to be assigned something other than `NULL` before `*ptr` occurred. My point was simply that global values do not get initialized to garbage values - they get zeroed out.

Comment: Oh ok. So if the `IF` statement was correct `ptr` would still be `NULL`?

Comment: Yes. The programmer's error of using the assignment operator instead of the comparison operator actually prevented the dereferencing of a `NULL` pointer in the `else` branch.

Comment: @charliescott yeah... I edited the comparator part like 17 minutes ago...

Comment: @Ilian ok. In the edit of the code I can currently see you don't need the if statement at all. You could just set `*ptr` to 1. Also reassigning the pointer to array in the function means `ptr` will always == `array` so you will step the pointer and then reset it to the initial value meaning nothing but count changes. (I'd put this under the main post but don't have enough karma)

Comment: @charliescott Thanks for the reply. I just assumed that everyone saw the edits I made. That was my bad. I know it seems like a really dumb code, but it's the oversimplified version of the original code. To clarify a little, I sort of need the if-else statement and the pointer for later when I use an interrupt function to shift the numbers down the array, and doing other modifications.